# How to get the selected row index and that selected row's cell value using delete button

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have use the templete field delete button in gridview, so when I click on any delete button in the gridview to delete a row at that time it will give the deleting row index with that selected row's `cells[0]` value. How can I do any one have a idea....?

```
protected void GridView3_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        int grdid = Int32.Parse(GridView3.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);

        IndiesProductDataContext ip = new IndiesProductDataContext();
        ip.iLinks.DeleteAllOnSubmit(ip.iLinks.Where(c => c.ProductID == grdid));
        ip.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I am using row command in gridview deleting row geting index but it does not work

Answer (score 5):

You can set CommandArgument property of button

In Aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteContact" CommandName="DeleteContact" 
CommandArgument="<%# Eval("ContactID") %>" runat="server" >Delete</asp:Button>
```

In _RowCommand event of GridView:

```
If e.CommandName = "DeleteContact" Then
    Dim  objContacts As New CContacts

    objContacts.ContactID = e.CommandArgument
    objContacts.DomainID = Session("DomainID")
    Dim strError As String = objContacts.DelContact()

End If
```

hope it helps

Comment: Chintan @ Probably he is using C# with asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it in that way but you will have to use buttons click event to select the ID and then use that ID as perameter for second, different delete query.

Comment: But i have to delete same selected row and also want to delete the another table value form selected row primary cell value...

Comment: Yup, you can write 2 separate delete query for your 2 different records from different table under the same sql connection with different sql command variables.

Answer (score 0):

i found The perfect solution of this problem...

```
    protected void GridView3_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
        int ci = Int32.Parse(GridView3.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);

        ProductDataContext ip = new ProductDataContext();
        ip.iLinks.DeleteAllOnSubmit(ip.iLinks.Where(c => c.PID == ci));
        ip.SubmitChanges();

    }
```

this code worked properly in my module...